Renaming /docs sub folders not changing the nav
I renamed the /docs sub folders and files but doesn't reflect on the browser for some weird reason. Note that the link changed but not the visible texts
I was expecting since I've components that it reflect on the screen and not on the link url.


So I figured out there is a _category.json that supersedes sub-folders names that is used instead in navbar generation.
